# how to select a part of a text column as new column in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have a text column that save a json string on it.
I want to select specific element of json as new column and i do not want to change type of this column to json.
Is it possible?
How can i do that?

My table name is 'logs' and my column name is 'response' and my target element in JSON string is 'server_response_time'.

Comment: Use JSON_EXTRACT(), for example. If your text column contains valid JSON (JSON_VALID(column) returns 1) then it will be processed correctly.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a valid JSON string stored in a string column, you can directly use JSON functions on it. MySQL will happily convert it to JSON under the hood.

So:

```
with t as (select  '{"foo": "bar", "baz": "zoo"}' col)
select col, col ->> '$.foo' as foo
from t
```

If your string is not valid JSON, this generates a runtime error. This is one of the reasons why I would still recommend storing your data as `JSON` rather than string: that way, data integrity is enforced at the time when your data is stored, rather than delayed until it is read.

Comment: yes @GMB. my string is a valid JSON, but i want to select all values of a specific element like 'foo' and store it in new column.

Comment: i get a syntax error: > 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax